# Why is the result of strcat empty

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, string-literals, strcat

```
char* path = malloc(128);
path = "/bin/"
char* path2 = malloc(128);
path2 = "ls"
strcat(path,path2);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

The result is empty.

But if I use

```
char path[128] = "/bin/";
char* path2 = malloc(128);
path2 = "ls"
strcat(path,path2);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

what is the difference between
char path[128] and malloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below code

```
char* path = malloc(128);
path = "/bin/";                   //added ;, you're overwriting the returned pointer
char* path2 = malloc(128);
path2 = "ls";                     // same as above
strcat(path,path2);               // the destination buffer is non-modifiable!!
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

you're essentially overwriting the memory (pointer) returned by allocator function, **and** making those pointers point to string literal. The `strcat()` call, thus, invokes undefined behaviour, as the destination buffer is non-modifiable (as they're string literal). This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The second snippet is less problematic

```
char path[128] = "/bin/";   // this is to be used as destination, OK
char* path2 = malloc(128);
path2 = "ls";               // you wouldn't need malloc here            
strcat(path,path2);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

here, you're allocating a large enough array (which is modifiable and can be used as a legit destination buffer for `strcat()`), so from that aspect you're okay. However, for the second argument, you're again overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc()`, causing memory leak. You don't need to use `malloc()` here, just assign the literal to the pointer and use that as the second argument in the `strcat()` call.

Comment: why can I get the correct result even though path2 is incorrect either in my second example?

Comment: @MarsEclipse Case 1: Undefined behaviour. Case 2: It's not a syntactical error, but not enough to stop you from running the program and getting output. The memory leak becomes a problem at a later point of time.

Answer (score 2):

`char*` does not work like a "string type" in other languages. It is a pointer, so when you write:

```
char* path = malloc(128);
path = "/bin/"
```

The memory returned by `malloc` is leaked since you lost the pointer to it.

Then, when you try to concatenate memory into the memory where the literal `"/bin/"` was saved, you get undefined behavior since you are trying to modify the memory that backs a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

Let me annotate these for you...

The first example leaks 256 bytes of memory and may crash, depending on where the constants reside in memory.

```
// Declare pointer path; malloc 128 bytes of heap memory and assign the address
char* path = malloc(128);
// Reassign the pointer (losing track of the malloc) to a string constant
// (could be in read-only memory if the compiler has deemed it wise)
path = "/bin/";
// Declare pointer path2; malloc 128 bytes of heap memory and assign the address
char* path2 = malloc(128);
// Reassign the pointer (losing track of the malloc) to a string constant
// (could be in read-only memory if the compiler has deemed it wise)
path2 = "ls";
// Attempt to concatenate strings; if `path` resides in read-only memory, this will segfault.
strcat(path, path2);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

The second example leaks 128 bytes of memory but should not crash (with these values; with e.g. user input, you'd have to be careful to use `strncat`).

```
// Declare pointer path to point to 128 bytes of stack memory (assuming in-function)
// and initialize it to "/bin/"
char path[128] = "/bin/";
// Declare pointer path2; malloc 128 bytes of heap memory and assign the address
char* path2 = malloc(128);
// Reassign the pointer (losing track of the malloc) to a string constant
// (could be in read-only memory if the compiler has deemed it wise)
path2 = "ls";
// Concatenate path2 to path in stack memory; this is fine (but could overflow)
strcat(path, path2);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```

The correct way would be something like this (if you're not going to return `path`, which is stack-allocated). This doesn't take care of overflows though.

```
// Declare pointer path to point to 128 bytes of stack memory (assuming in-function)
// and initialize it to "/bin/"
char path[128] = "/bin/";
// Concatenate the constant "ls" to path in stack memory (could still overflow)
strcat(path, "ls");
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",path);
```